# Pandas integrate over columns per each row

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, numerical-integration

In a simplified dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd 

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'350': [7.898167, 6.912074, 6.049002, 5.000357, 4.072320],
                '351': [8.094912, 7.090584, 6.221289, 5.154516, 4.211746],
                '352': [8.291657, 7.269095, 6.393576, 5.308674, 4.351173],
                '353': [8.421007, 7.374317, 6.496641, 5.403691, 4.439815],
                '354': [8.535562, 7.463452, 6.584512, 5.485725, 4.517310],
                '355': [8.650118, 7.552586, 6.672383, 4.517310, 4.594806]},
                 index=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

int_range = df1.columns.astype(float)
a = 0.005
b = 0.837
```

I would like to solve an equation which is attached as an image below:

[image]

**I** is equal to the values in the data frame. x is the **int_range** values so in this case from 350 to 355 with a dx=1.
**a** and **b** are optional constants

I need to get a dataframe as an output per **each row**

For now I do something like this, but I'm not sure it's correct:

```
dict_INT = {}
for index, row in df1.iterrows():

    func = df1.loc[index]*df1.loc[index].index.astype('float')
    x    = df1.loc[index].index.astype('float')

    dict_INT[index] = integrate.trapz(func, x)

df_out = pd.DataFrame(dict_INT, index=['INT']).T

df_fin = df_out/(a*b)
```

This is the final sum I get per row:

```
1  3.505796e+06
2  3.068796e+06
3  2.700446e+06
4  2.199336e+06
5  1.840992e+06
```

Comment: So `I` isn't actually a constant and is instead `I(x)`?. If that's the case you probably want [`scipy.integrate.cumtrapz`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.cumtrapz.html)

Comment: yes, it changes with x, of course, I'll update the picture, that wasn't clear.

Comment: What does the desired output look like?

Comment: I guess it should result to one column of integrated values with the same number of rows as before

Comment: @ALollz, how would you then implement it in this particular case=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by first converting the dataframe to dict and then performing your equation by each item in row, then writing these value to dict using collections defaultdict. I will break it down:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'350': [7.898167, 6.912074, 6.049002, 5.000357, 4.072320],
                '351': [8.094912, 7.090584, 6.221289, 5.154516, 4.211746],
                '352': [8.291657, 7.269095, 6.393576, 5.308674, 4.351173],
                '353': [8.421007, 7.374317, 6.496641, 5.403691, 4.439815],
                '354': [8.535562, 7.463452, 6.584512, 5.485725, 4.517310],
                '355': [8.650118, 7.552586, 6.672383, 4.517310, 4.594806]},
                index=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
                 )

int_range = df1.columns.astype(float)
a = 0.005
b = 0.837
dx = 1
df_dict = df1.to_dict() # convert df to dict for easier operations

integrated_dict = {} # initialize empty dict

d = defaultdict(list) # initialize empty dict of lists for tuples later
integrated_list = []
for k,v in df_dict.items(): # unpack df dict of dicts
    for x,y in v.items(): # unpack dicts by column and index (x is index, y is column)
        integrated_list.append((k, (((float(k)*float(y)*float(dx))/(a*b))))) #store a list of tuples.


for x,y in integrated_list: # create dict with column header as key and new integrated calc as value (currently a tuple)
    d[x].append(y)


d = {k:tuple(v) for k, v in d.items()} # unpack to multiple values

integrated_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d) # to df
integrated_df['Sum'] = integrated_df.iloc[:, :].sum(axis=1)
```

output (updated to include sum):

```
             350            351            352            353            354  \
0  660539.653524  678928.103226  697410.576822  710302.382557  722004.527599   
1  578070.704898  594694.141935  611402.972521  622015.269056  631317.086738   
2  505890.250896  521785.529032  537763.142652  547984.294624  556969.473835   
3  418189.952210  432314.245161  446512.126165  455795.202628  464025.483871   
4  340576.344086  353243.212903  365976.797133  374493.356033  382109.376344   

         355             Sum
0  733761.502987  4.202947e+06
1  640661.416965  3.678162e+06
2  565996.646356  3.236389e+06
3  383188.781362  2.600026e+06
4  389762.516129  2.206162e+06
```

Comment: You're basically doing a left Riemann sum here, and your value matches my "rough" calculation if I toss the rightmost column and sum over the columns of your `integrated_df`, _if_ I remove your multiplication by `float(k)`. I'm not sure why you're doing that.

Comment: Yeah this is what I noticed, that my value matches your rough value if I take away float(k). Let's take the first value at 350 for example (7.898167). I(x) reduces to the value of 7.898167 as defined by him. x evaluates to 350 in this case as he said this was the column value, and ab are constants 0.005 and 0.837 respectively. Basically, I(x) evaluates to the solution of the equation (a value) (x/ab) evaluates to a constant, and dx evaluates to 1 (constant). I do not understand why x would not be included I guess. Thanks for the help anyway!

Comment: Last time I'll post. I am evaluating the expression as x/ab = c so we have the following: `definiteIntegral(I(x))*c dx` so for each definiteIntegral evaluates to `c*(definiteIntegral(I(x)dx))` where c=350/(0.005*0.837) in this case.

Comment: You just convinced me I'm wrong-- for some reason I kept not seeing the `x` in the the integrand!  I could fix my original answer by multiplying by `x` but now I feel silly, so I'm going to walk away. :-)

Comment: If someone says that hasn't happened before and they do math often they are lying! Your answer is better, you should just edit it so it stays available. I wasn't even aware of the function you used so I learned today, you just had me quadruple checking my math haha. Take care!

Comment: @d_kennetz , thank you so much for your post, comments and suggestions, that's extremely helpful! I just have a minor problem in understanding, you see, the output here stays per each column, what the final output should be is one summing column. So do I just sum the values per row as the final result?

Comment: I hope he posts his answer back, I truly do think his answer is better as it is more concise. Mine does not take advantage of the libraries made for this stuff. Yes for the final over the definite integral you would just sum the items in a row and output it in a final column, sorry I didn’t include that! I would add it in but I am currently on mobile.

Comment: @d_kennetz, could I kindly ask you to take a look at my version of the code? 
I updated the question. The values differ from yours, so I'm not sure where I'm getting it wrong

Comment: Hi @PEBKAC I updated my answer to include the sum column, which I should've included initially. Your answer is more accurate than mine because you are performing the integration over the function and then applying the constant after the integration occurs (which is how those operations should be handled). My answer performs the integration with the constants included which is changing our final out. I think you have solved your code. Could you reaccept my answer after you compare your output to mine? Our answers are on the same order of magnitude and are differing by a constant value.

Comment: yes sorry I just wanted to get your attention in case you don't read the comment, I am still considering it a super answer

Comment: x term is handled in the integrated_list.append line. I am generating a list of tuples there, one with the key (index value) and the other with the resultant math. The next bit is shaping the dictionary to be able to be turned back into a dataframe.

Comment: I see what you are asking, no there shouldn't be x**2/2 after integration since f(x) is included in your integrand (x/ab) is treated as a constant. so your integrand is evaluated as (x/ab) *(integrand[350->355] I(x)dx). See the discussion I had with DSM earlier about this.

Comment: yeah, I rechecked the code and realized immediately that it doesn't make sense what I asked. Cool, still the results quite differ, thus I wasn't sure about it...better ask than stay ignorant ;-) Thanks again!